# Find the probability $\mathbb{P}(U\leq z|U+M=y)$ given $U,M\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I came here to verify whether my solution is correct or not. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is valid:

---

Let $U,M$ such that $U,M\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Assume $U,M$ are statistically independent. Define:

$$\Phi(x)\triangleq\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\ \text{d}t\qquad f(t)\triangleq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}$$

Find the probability $p\triangleq\mathbb{P}(U\leq z|U+M=y)$.

---

**My Attempt**:

$$p\underset{(\star)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(U\leq z|U+M=y,M=m)f(m)\ \text{d}m\underset{(\star\star)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(U\leq z|U=y-m)f(m)\ \text{d}m = \\= \int_{y-z}^{\infty}f(m)\ \text{d}m=1-\Phi(y-z)$$

What I'm most unsure about is $(\star)$. $(\star\star)$ is justified (I hope) since $U,M$ are statistically independent.

Thanks!

Comment: why does $(\star\star)$ require any type of independence?

Comment: @DanielAdams Because if they were dependent, $M=m$ is an additional information that might affect $U$ since they're dependent. I removed the condition $M=m$ **because** $M$ and $U$ are independent, therefore the fact that $M$ is known doesn't contribute to the value of $U$.

(For example: if $M=2U$ then $M=m$ implies $U=m/2$; This changes the integral)

Comment: Regardless of their independence you would know the value of $U$ since you also knew $ U=y-M $.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the solution more simply as :

\begin{align}
P(U\leq z | U+M =y )=&P(y-M\leq z)= P(M\geq y-z)=1-P(M\leq y-z),
\end{align}

and using the CDF for $M$ you have the result.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(U\leq z|U+M=y) = \mathbb{P}(y-M \leq z|U+M=y)$,
with that I agree, but why did you remove the condition? $U+M$ and $M$ aren't independent, are they?

Comment: Their independence doesn't matter.

Comment: $P(U\leq z | U+M =y )=P(U\leq z | U =y-M )$ this is asking for the probability that $U\leq z$ given that we know its distribution is $U \sim \mathcal{N}(y,1)$. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your solution and I appreciate it, but the main purpose of my thread is just to verify whether what I chose to do is correct or not. My question is of course a simplification of a much more complicated problem, in which I used similar methods, and I just want to know if they're valid.

Comment: Your solutions good :)

Answer (score 0):

The conditional distribution of $U$ given $U+M$ is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2):
$$
U\mid (U+M)=y\sim N(y/2,1/2).
$$